# Get NullPointerException from calling org.apache.lucene.benchmark.byTask.feeds.TrecGov2Parser.parse

Tags: java, lucene

I want to pars GOv2 collection format and I want to use **TrecGov2Parser**. I find its code in this [page](https://github.com/yintaoxue/read-open-source-code/blob/master/lucene-4.7.2/src/org/apache/lucene/benchmark/byTask/feeds/TrecGov2Parser.java). The input file is test file and it contains just one document of GOV2 collection.
This is my code:

```
public static void writeHTMLText()
{
    try
    {
        FileWriter fw1= new FileWriter(new File("/home/fl/Desktop/GOV_Text/GOV/00.txt"));
        BufferedWriter bw1 = new BufferedWriter(fw1);

        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(new File("/home/fl/Desktop/GOV/00"));
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        String docs="";
        String line;
        while((line=br.readLine())!= null )
              docs= docs+line+"\n";

        DocData docData = new DocData();
        DocData result = new TrecGov2Parser().parse(docData,"result00",new TrecContentSource(),new StringBuilder(docs),TrecDocParser.ParsePathType.GOV2);
        bw1.write(result.getBody());

        br.close();
        bw1.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I got this error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.lucene.benchmark.byTask.feeds.TrecGov2Parser.parse(TrecGov2Parser.java:56)
    at LuceneParser.parserInput.writeHTMLText(parserInput.java:63)
I add *lucene-core-3.4.0.jar* and *lucene-benchmark-3.4.0.jar* to my project buildpath.
```

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `private`, `protected` or `public` keyword at [`getHtmlParser()`](https://github.com/yintaoxue/read-open-source-code/blob/master/lucene-4.7.2/src/org/apache/lucene/benchmark/byTask/feeds/TrecContentSource.java#L123). This means you can call this method only from inside the same package (**default/package visibility**). The method is **intended not to be used by others**.

Comment: how can I use TrecGov2Parser function?

Comment: You have to create an instance of  the `TrecGov2Parser` class and use the `parse(...)` method: `DocData result = new TrecGov2Parser().parse(...);`

Comment: Could you tell me how should I give inputs to **parse** function? I update my question.

Comment: That's another question you should ask separately. But maybe you solve the puzzle yourself by debugging, which variable is why `null` and how to avoid it. Looks like you're close to the solution. Happy coding! ;-)